# Notation for a periodic interval?

Tags: notation

For instance, if I want to describe the position on a circle I can write that the angle $\theta$ can be found in the interval $[0, \tau)$, but how can I express that this interval is periodic, e.g. that $0$ and $\tau^-$ are "glued" together?

Comment: Do you mean $\theta \in [0+ 2k\pi, \tau + 2k\pi)$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Andrew that seems appropriate, but needlessly complicated.

Comment: How about $[0,\tau) + 2\pi \mathbb Z$ then?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew suggested, you can write:
$$
    [0,\tau)\ +\ 2\pi\mathbb{Z}
$$
or using [quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function#Quotient_spaces_as_domain) notation:
$$
    [0,\tau)\ /\ 2\pi\mathbb{Z}
$$